# Clear the ightning-input field value to empty after click on save button

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Want to clear the Input field value to empty, when we click on save button.

Tried in following ways

1. `this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(each => {each.value = '';});`
2. `this.template.querySelector('form').reset();`

Both is not working, CAn you help me on this.

**HTML**

```
 <template if:true={parentsRet}>
                            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
                                <div class="demo-only demo-only--sizing slds-grid slds-wrap">
                                    <div class="slds-size_2-of-4">
                                        <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                                            <lightning-input label="First Name" value={firstname}
                                                onchange={handleChange} name="firstname" required></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-size_2-of-4">
                                        <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">

                                            <lightning-input label="Last Name" value={lastName}
                                                onchange={handleChange} name="lastName" required></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-size_2-of-4">
                                        <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">

                                            <lightning-input label="Phone" value={phone} onchange={handleChange}
                                                name="phone" required></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-size_2-of-4">
                                        <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                                            <lightning-input label="Email" value={email} onchange={handleChange}
                                                name="email" required></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-size_2-of-2">
                                        <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                                            <lightning-input-field field-name="Student_Relation__c"
                                                onchange={handleChange} name="relationship" required>
                                            </lightning-input-field>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-size_2-of-2">
                                        <lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" value="AddParent"
                                            name="AddParent" label="Save" onclick={handleonClickParentSave}>
                                        </lightning-button>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </lightning-record-edit-form>
                        </template>
```

**JS**

```
 handleonClickParentSave() {
/*  console.log("firstname  ---" + this.firstname);
console.log("lastName  ---" + this.lastName);
console.log("phone  ---" + this.phone);
console.log("email  ---" + this.email);
console.log("relationship  ---" + this.relationship);*/

createParentGuardian({
  firstName: this.firstname,
  lastName: this.lastName,
  phone: this.phone,
  email: this.email,
  studentRelation: this.relationship,
  enrollmentName: this.recordId
})
  .then(result => {
    this.returnResult = result;
    console.log("this.returnResult --> " + this.returnResult);
    if (result) {
      console.log("result1 -->" + this.returnResult);
      this.variant = "success";
      this.title = "Success";
      this.message = "Sucessfully Created";
      this.selectedItems = "parent_guardian";
    } else {
      console.log("result1 Else -->" + this.returnResult);
      this.variant = "error";
      this.title = "Error";
      this.message = "Failed to Create";
    }
    return refreshApex(this.wiredDataRefresh);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.returnResult = false;
    if (error) {
      console.log("result2 -->" + this.returnResult);
      this.variant = "error";
      this.title = "Error";
      this.message = error;
    }
    console.log("error -->" + error);
  });

if (this.returnResult) {
  console.log("result1 -->" + this.returnResult);
  this.variant = "success";
  this.title = "Success";
  this.message = "Sucessfully Created";      
} else {
  console.log("result2 -->" + this.returnResult);
  this.variant = "error";
  this.title = "Error";
  this.message = "Failed to Create";
}

const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
  title: this.title,
  message: this.message,
  variant: this.variant
});
this.dispatchEvent(evt);
this.variant = "";
const toastModel = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="toastModel"]');
toastModel.className = "slds-show";

this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
  const toastModel = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="toastModel"]');
  toastModel.className = "slds-hide";
}, this.autoCloseTime);

this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(each => {each.value = '';});
 //this.template.querySelector('form').reset();
}
```

Comment: to reset lightning-input this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(each => {each.value = '';}); work. The execution does not reach the line where you reset lightning-input. Check if you don't have an exception in your apex method And don’t use name in lightning-input-field attribute [lightning input field specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification)`